# What kind of tense is being used in this sentence?

Tags: tenses

What kind of tense is being used in this sentence?

> If you could travel anywhere in the world, where would you want to go?

Comment: The events described by your verbs haven't happened yet, so it's future tense.

Comment: @pabrams This is not true. If *could* is some verb's "future tense" inflection, pray tell us then what its past and present tenses are.

Comment: Second conditional.

Comment: @tchrist Huh? English doesn't use inflection to express future tense.  That's why we use auxiliaries like "will" and "would". Pray give us an example of _any_ verb using a future inflection.

Comment: Are you asking about *tense* or *mood*?

Comment: @Lawrence The question says "tense"...

Comment: @pabrams That's why I asked. The words "could" and "would" are words in the past tense but used to refer to the future. On the other hand, "If you could" indicates a counterfactual, which is more usefully analysed in terms of mood, rather than tense.

Comment: @Lawrence Are you saying that sentence is in past tense? If you wanted past tense you'd say "could *have travelled*", and "would *have wanted to go*". I don't know why you're going on about counter-whatsits and your mood; the question is about tense.

Comment: @pabrams No, you’ve misunderstood. I was referring to tenses of individual words. Have a look at [grammatical mood](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_mood), particularly the irrealis moods. After that, please read my previous comment again.

Comment: @Lawrence No, I think you've misunderstood. The question is not about the tense of individual words, the question is about the tense of a sentence.  If you want to talk about other things, such as the tense of individual words, or grammatical mood, you should go comment on questions about those things, instead of commenting here.  And on top of that, you're wrong, anyway.  The word "could" isn't always used in past tense, and "would" certainly isn't.

Comment: @tchrist To answer your original question, the past-tense version of the sentence would be "If you could have traveled anywhere in the world, where would you have wanted to go?"

Comment: @pabrams That brings us full circle to my question to the Original Poster (OP), which hasn’t yet been answered by the OP. Since we’ve gone full-circle, I’ll leave you to consider whether it’s possible that grammarians use terms that sound familiar to the lay person but which are imbued with precise, technical meaning.

Comment: Of course it's possible he meant what you want him to have meant, but I usually assume people mean what they say, unless I have good reason to believe otherwise.

Comment: It doesn't matter, though, because your other premise is wrong, too.  _Could_ and _would_ are not "words in the past tense"; they can be used in past, present or future.

Answer (score 1):

**Future tense**

https://www.englishpage.com/modals/could.html

As per the source

**"Could" is a modal verb used to express possibility or past ability as well as to make suggestions and requests. "Could" is also commonly used in *conditional* sentences as the conditional form of "can."** It is used in Past, Present and Future tense.

In **If you could travel anywhere in the world, where would you want to go?**, could is being used as the conditional of 'can'.

https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar/will-or-would

**As per the source *would* is used to talk about hypotheses, about something which is possible but not real:**

It is being used to talk about the result or effect of a possible situation:
EG: It would be very expensive to stay in a hotel

Comment: Conditional isn't a tense. According to your link, the sentence in the question is future tense.

Comment: I see you fixed it - upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is in future tense.  Take a look at the examples at [this link](https://www.englishpage.com/modals/could.html), particularly the positive forms in future tense.

Answer (score 0):

It's a conditional sentence with "if." You use "would" to talk about imaginary situations. You can use any tense in the "if" part and "would" in the other part to signify the imaginary situation.

Hope I answered your question.

I recommend the following sites for great grammar info:

http://www.queens-english-society.com

http://englishisducksoup.com

Comment: Although you can use a conditional with any tense, the sentence in question is in the future tense.  In the past tense, it would use "could have" and "would have", and in the present tense the conditional would be something like "When you can travel anywhere in the world, where do you go?" (Would read better using "when" instead of "if".)

Comment: pabrams - let's stay on "if" here. I can say, "If you had money to buy anything, what would you buy?" right? Here, the tense in the "if" part is the past tense and it still refers to a future event.

Comment: "If you had money to buy anything, what would you buy?" is future tense.   You can't say the first part of the sentence is past tense, because "if you had money to buy anything" doesn't make sense by itself. Although the word "had" might mislead some people into thinking that portion of the sentence is past tense, it's not; it's actually future.  If it was past tense, you would use "had had", as in "If you had had money to buy anything, what would you have bought?"

Comment: And anyway, you haven't answered the question.  He asked about the tense of the sentence, and you answered "it's conditional".  Conditional is not a tense.